# IP recognition .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Right now we have a .htpasswd and a .htaccess file. Everybody has their own page which you will be redirected to if you enter valid credentials.

My question is the following:
We want to enter ip's and according to the ip we want to sent someone to the right page.

I know this:

```
<Files 403.shtml>
   order deny,allow
   deny from all
</Files>

allow from 142.4.98.37
allow from 193.105.210.217
allow from 142.4.98.35
```

but this isn't the right solution for me since everybody has a different page.

I really hope someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance for the time taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the authentication has been verified (`Require valid-user`), you can use rewrite rules with conditions:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^127\.0\.0\.1
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.example.com/somepage.html [R=301,L]
```

This would redirect the user with IP 127.0.0.1 to http://www.example.com/somepage.html

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks

Comment: You can also use just `^` instead of `^.*$`.